# isdigit() function pass a Chinese parameter

Tags: c++

When I try using the `isdigit()` function with a Chinese character, it reports an assert in Visual Studio 2013 in Debug mode, but there is no problem in Release mode.

I think if this function is to determine whether the parameter is a digit, why does it not return 0 if the Chinese is wrong?

This is my code:

```cpp
string testString = "abcdefg12345中文";
int count = 0;
for (const auto &c : testString) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

and this is the assert :

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use the [locale enabled `isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit).

Comment: Can this work, given that `std::string` is `char` based?  Have you looked in the debugger to see exactly what the byte value of those characters are?  I am always wary of non-ASCII quoted text in source files, since it is not clear exactly what will show up at runtime.

Comment: The `isdigit` you're using has a precondition that the character has an unsigned value or is EOF. Argue all you want about what it *should* do, but it won't change the fact that this precondition exists. And note that the chance of those hanzi being a single `char` each is effectively zero. If you want full Unicode support, there are options like ICU.

Comment: Three answers in the comments. No peer review possible. SMH.

Answer (score 5):

You broke the contract of [`isdigit(int)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), which expects only ASCII characters in the range stated.

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

Your standard library implementation is being kind and asserting, rather than going on to blow stuff up.

There is an alternative, locale-aware [`isdigit(charT ch, const locale&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit) that you may be able to use here.

I suggest performing some further research on how "characters" work in computers, particularly with regards to encoding more "exotic"<sup>1</sup> character sets.

<sub><sup>1</sup> From the perspective of computer history. Of course, to you, it is the *less* exotic alternative!</sub>

Comment: But for the isdigit(), why not when the parameters of the transmission of the ASCII code is not between 0-9 to return 0, but throw an exception for the user to deal with, I think this lost the original meaning of the function

Comment: @Citron: The function _never_ meant to handle any inputs outside of the ASCII range. It never supported "Chinese characters". If you are providing Chinese characters, then you are not using ASCII, so the "not between 0-9" condition no longer necessarily holds (this is a condition given by ASCII). I think you may need to do some further research on how character encodings work in computers, as I suggested yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The `isdigit()` and related functions / macros in `<ctypes.h>` expect an `int` converted from an `unsigned char`, or `EOF`, which on most systems means a value in the range 0-255 (or -1 for `EOF`).  So any value not in the range -1…255 is incorrect.

**Problem 1:** You are passing in a `char`, which on your system has range -128…+127.  Solution to this problem is simple:

```
if (isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)))
```

This won't crash, however, it's not quite correct for Chinese characters.

**Problem 2:** Non-ASCII characters should probably use `iswdigit()` instead.  This will correctly handle Chinese characters:

```
wstring testString = L"abcdefg12345中文";
int count = 0;
for (const auto &c : testString) {
    if (iswdigit(c)) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if the characters are encoded in UTF-8, then using `iswdigit()` would require converting them to the platform's wide character encoding before passing them.

Comment: @JustinTime: Wide characters cannot be encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: The OP wasn't using wide characters to begin with, though, so I don't know why you'd bring that up; note their use of `string`, not `wstring`.  `中` is `\xE4\xB8\xAD` in UTF-8, and `文` is `\xE6\x96\x87`.  As I said, it might be worth mentioning that if the characters are encoded in UTF-8, using `iswdigit()` would require converting them into wide characters first.

Comment: @JustinTime: "The OP wasn't using wide characters to begin with"... that was exactly my suggestion: to use wide characters, hence the use of `L"..."` string literals and `wstring` instead of `"..."` and `string`.  Somehow that message got lost.  The encoding is often not UTF-8 for `string` anyway, you would need to use `u8"..."` for your string literals.  In Visual Studio (which the OP is using) you will often get some code page for your application, and UTF-8 isn't one of the options.

Comment: @JustinTime: To elaborate--if you paste arbitrary Unicode characters into your source file in Visual Studio, it will save the file using a Unicode encoding, but the encoding for plain string literals will be converted to the appropriate code page (but never UTF-8) at compile time.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  I was just pointing out that since he's indicated that his data is in an encoding that can be stored in regular `char`s (which I presumed to be UTF-8, due to `std::string` pulling double duty as the ASCII `basic_string` and the UTF-8 `basic_string`, although it has some issues with the latter due to seeing each individual byte as a character), he would have to convert it to a wide encoding before passing it to code that expects wide characters.

Comment: And to be fair, [they're working on adding UTF-8 support to MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708821.aspx).  MSVC also lets you specify [the source file's encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx) and [the encoding for literals embedded into the executable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708818.aspx) (with the first option just being a shortcut for setting both to UTF-8), although I haven't tested how well this works yet.