# Debug Assertion Failed when Inputting £ Symbol

Tags: c++

I'm getting a strange error which doesn't like it when I input the £ symbol. Anyone know why? Or rather know how to fix it? When £ sign is entered it causes  an error message "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library"

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool CheckError(std::string sLine, std::string &sName)
{
    bool bError = false;
    try
    {
        if (any_of(sLine.begin(),sLine.end(), isdigit))
        {
            cout << "Error.\n";
            bError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bError = false;
            sName = sLine;
        }
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        bError = true;
        cout << "Error";
    }
     return bError;

}
void Input(std::string sMessage, std::string &sLine)
{
    cout << sMessage;
    getline(cin, sLine);
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::string sName = "";
    std::string sLine = "";

    do
    {
        //When £ sign is entered it causes  an error message "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library"
        //It says something about Expression: c>= -1 && c<=255
        Input("Input your name: ", sLine);
    }
    while(CheckError(sLine, sName));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isdigit() function pass a Chinese parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544690/isdigit-function-pass-a-chinese-parameter)

Comment: @Jonny Henly I don't think thats a good dupe, its not very clearly worded and the answers (while relevent) do not explain that it is a unicode issue

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 Nice dupe find! You're definitely right about the dupe I suggested, yours addresses the problem in a much better way.